# Page flickers on load - hide/show javascript - Total Newbie

Tags: javascript, css

Ok so here goes.. I'm totally new to Javascript. I only started on html&css about a month ago. All my htl and css is probably pretty backward and i've got a stack to learn. I'm using two pieces of javascript - one piece loads the nivo slider and the other the hide and show easy tabs:

http://www.kollermedia.at/archive/2007/07/04/easy-tabs-11-free-tab-menu/

Both were fine when I hacked them to hell trying to get them to look the way I wanted. Since i've put them together all hell has broken loose (bit of an exageration) but it may as well have because although they are both working, the page flickers badly on load. I have been researching this and I hear it's called DOM flicker. I know it's due to the hidden divs showing before the script kicks in. I also notice that the increased page height, for the split second (sometimes longer) it takes the content to hide activates the scroll bars and i know this could have an affect. I'm also using background images within the links on mouse over commands.... i didn't know what else to do.

I've read you can add script to only show the content once the script has loaded but I know zero javascript : ) ... yet!

Can somebody please help me fix this? I've read lots of posts around the net but they all put the code with gaps where your supposed to fill in and where it's put is expected to be known. I'm sorry to be such a mong but could someone literally copy and paste my javascript and edit that to show me?

I know it's a lot too ask but i've been trying to fix this all day. 
Here's a link showing the problem (when selecting the portfolio links the delay / flicker lasts ages!)

link to the site: http://www.adam-ashton.co.uk/homepage.html

(sorry to be so long winded)

Thanks,
David

Comment: Welcome to stack overload David. Please don't be discouraged, but it is not proper etiquette here to post questions asking "please help me fix this". You need to state a specific problem and post code that demonstrates your problem - not just a link to code at another site

Comment: What browser are you witnessing this with?  for javascript questions look at http://jsfiddle.net/ - You can put your code in there and have people run it and fix it.  Good luck.

Comment: @ControlAltDel my apologies, i meant no offence i just thought it may be helpful to show the original before my adjustments.

Comment: @JeffV  thanks for the link, i'm testing in safari and firefox for now. I know this is a common question asked it's implementing the answers that i find so difficult (what code where and when)

Answer (score 3):

Page Flicker can be handled with the help of some css

```
.hideME {

visibility:hidden;
}
```

Add this class to the Top Most Element (Mostly a div ) of you html page

And inside the script tag ,

write a window.load function

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $(selector).removeClass('hideMe');
});
```

this should do the magic :)

Comment: Wow thanks for the super quick response! I"ll give this a shot now. :)

Comment: ... ok so I've added the additionnal CSS, added the class=hideME to my content and it's disappeared... but it doesn't come back. Could it be this command is interfering:                                       window.onload=function(){
var menucount=loadtabs.length; var a = 0; var b = 1; do {easytabs(b, loadtabs[a]);  a++; b++;}while (b<=menucount);
if (autochangemenu!=0){start_autochange();}
}

Comment: did u give the proper selector that i have mentioned inside window.load??...post the div which u added that css

Comment: I've put the code up here as screenshots, thank you massively for your help on this i really do appreciate it. Currently the css works to hide but on preview i get nothing. :http://www.adam-ashton.co.uk/code.html

Comment: I've updated the screenshots, I'm getting a syntax error: adam-ashton.co.uk/code.html, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this one line code at 46th line .. Means first line of window.load**

```
   $('.container').removeClass('hideMe');
```

Comment: I've updated the screenshots, I'm getting a syntax error: http://www.adam-ashton.co.uk/code.html, any thoughts?

Comment: add this at line number 10
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

Jquery files are not added so only.$ is not working..

Comment: Adding that code gives me the following:http://www.adam-ashton.co.uk/code.html It greys out the code, you have high patience levels! I am sorry for being a mong but I have zero javascript knowledge at the moment.

Comment: It's still not showing but the code shows no syntax errors, you've been so helpful. I have to pop out now and i'll have a play over the weekend. Can I check back with you Wednesday if it's still broke? Thanks again, and have a good double bank holiday if you're in the UK!